# How to delete a PWA on Android 11

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-21

I cannot for the life of me work out how to delete a PWA from android (on a Galaxy S21).

Google's own [support page says that it should appear in my apps list, and I should be able to uninstall it like any other app](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9658361?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid). However, it isn't listed there.

There's no menu in the PWA from which I could remove it.

I've tried removing the shortcut, but the pwa is still installed.

I can't find anything relevant in Chrome's menus, or anywhere in Android's settings pages.

I've tried going to chrome://apps as you can on desktop, but the page doesn't seem to exist on android.

Any tips?

Comment: You can search for that app in Settings

Answer (score 0):

Hold on the app icon in laucher, app info and uninstall.
if that doesn't work, Setting>apps and locate that pwa and uninstall.